# Problems with animating pictures in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a problem with the animation of sequence of pictures. I have created an ordered list of picture, but I have no experience with Tkinter and this is my first GUI, so I will appreciate your support. 
 This is the code:

```
def animation_creator(filename):
    infolabel.configure(text ="Creating " + filename +"animation" )
    """Make an ordered list of the images"""
    height=display.winfo_height()
    width=display.winfo_width()
    frames = [Image.open(image).resize(width, height) for image in sorted(glob.glob(f" 
    {folder}/{filename}*.JPG"))]
    frames = sorted(frames, key = lambda f: int(os.path.basename(f.filename).split('.')[0].split(' 
    ')[1]))
    frames2 = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=fr) for fr in frames]
    tkframe_sequence = itertools.cycle(frames2)
    #tkframe_iterator = iter(frames)
    global after_id
    after_id = root.after(100,nimh_server)
    img = next(tkframe_sequence)
    display.configure(image=img)
    display.image = img

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = 700, width = 800)
canvas.pack()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg = "green")
frame1.place(relx = 0.0, rely = 0.0, relheight=0.1, relwidth=1)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.place(relx = 0.0, rely = 0.2, relheight=0.8, relwidth=1)

button = tk.Button(frame1, text = "Test", command =lambda: nimh_server(PhotoIRBalkan) )
button.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.4, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.1)

interval = tk.Entry(frame1)
interval.place(relx = 0.6, rely = 0.4, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.1)


infolabel = tk.Label(frame2)
infolabel.pack()

display = tk.Label(frame1, text = "IDK" , bg = "green")
display.place(relx = 0.25, rely=0.7, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.5)
root.mainloop()
```

So in short I want to animate a sequence of pictures (PhotoIRBalkan 1.jpg,PhotoIRBalkan 2.jpg,PhotoIRBalkan 3.jpg,PhotoIRBalkan 4.jpg), and if possible resize them to the size of the widget. Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: Use `after` method to animate your images. Store the call to the `after` method in a variable to delete it, i.e., stop animation (if necessary) with `after_cancel(<variable name>)`

Comment: I don't have experience working with the after method can you give example code?

Comment: @GornaOryahovica there is enough example code on the internet about this (and on SO too), also take a look at some tutorials, you need to learn basics, there is also a lot of documentation and stuff, once you get stuck with **all** of theses resources and have a very specific problem that hasn't been answered here, then you can ask a question